# How can I use the onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

How can I use the onChangeSelect?

```
if (this.props.showFiltersHeader) {
            const { tipoBusqueda } = this.props;            
            return <div>
                <div className="search-container">
                    <p>Buscar por NIE o Factura</p>
                    <div className="caja-select">
                        <select onChange={this.onChangeSelect} name="filterFacturaNieType" value={this.state.filterFacturaNieType}>
                        {tipoBusqueda === 1 ? <option value='N'>NIE</option> : <option value='F'>Factura</option>}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <span className="alert-span">{this.state.errors["filterFacturaNieType"]}</span>
                </div>
....
}
```

```
onChangeSelect = (event) => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
};
```

it is correctly putting the option in the select, but it is not setting the selected value

Comment: yes, 'N' or 'F'

Answer (score 0):

try without your `tipoBusqueda === 1` condition like this. May be it happen that in your state value is `'F'` and your condition `tipoBusqueda === 1`
get true than there is no option available with this value than it will not show any selected value .

```
<div className="caja-select">
    <select onChange={this.onChangeSelect} name="filterFacturaNieType" value={this.state.filterFacturaNieType}>
        <option value='N'>NIE</option>
        <option value='F'>Factura</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @DanielAdrianGarayGarcia if this was helped you than please do upvote !!

Comment: I need it to be conditioned by tipoBusqueda

Comment: you can add but check without condition if its working than add condition .